# Elastic search has_child query

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a parent-child (one to many) relation in elastic search, and we want to check for all parent objects where it's child object attribute(child_attr) has any value in it.

we are generating json-queries as below:

1) For Has value condition.

```
{
                "has_child" : {
                  "query" : {
                    "filtered" : {
                      "query" : {
                        "match_all" : { }
                      },
                      "filter" : {
                        "and" : {
                          "filters" : [ {
                            "exists" : {
                              "field" : "child_attr"
                            }
                          }, {
                            "not" : {
                              "filter" : {
                                "term" : {
                                  "child_attr" : ""
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          } ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "type" : "child"
                }
              }
```

2) For Has No Value Condition

```
{
                "has_child" : {
                  "query" : {
                    "filtered" : {
                      "query" : {
                        "match_all" : { }
                      },
                      "filter" : {
                        "or" : {
                          "filters" : [ {
                            "missing" : {
                              "field" : "child_attr"
                            }
                          }, {
                            "term" : {
                              "child_attr" : ""
                            }
                          } ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "type" : "child"
                }
              }
```

These queries are returning only those parent objects where either all child objects have some value or all child objects have no value the searched attribute.

It doesn't return anything where this condition is met partially which covers majority of data.

I have also toyed with keyword analyzer to index this child_attribute but no joy.

Look forward to your expert suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting unexpected results because the query

```
"missing" : {
    "field" : "child_attr"
}
```

matches both records that were indexed with empty string in the `child_attr` and records in which `child_attr` was missing.

The query

```
"exists" : {
    "field" : "child_attr"
}
```

is exact oposite of the first query, it matches all records that were indexed with a non-empty `child_attr` field.

The query

```
"term" : {
    "child_attr" : ""
}
```

doesn't match anything.

Comment: I updated my sync code to make exists and missing filters to work. Thanks :)

Comment: hey is it possible to get child fields in a has child query?